# Осложнённое сказуемое с однородными частями разного типа

Tags: грамотная-речь, грамматика

*Работа всегда должна **быть интересной** и **приносить удовольствие**.*

Грамотно ли так говорить? При модальной связке *должен* стоят разнородные части сказуемого: одна содержит глагол-связку и именную часть, вторая — глагол.

Comment: Звучит нормально, и о запретах на такое построение мне ничего не известно (а вам?). А раз не запрещено, то можно.

Comment: @М_Г А вот мне слух слегка режет.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Звучит нормально, и о запретах на такое построение мне ничего не известно (а вам?). А раз не запрещено, то можно.

Пример  из Нацкорпуса:

> Россия **может быть на Кавказе носительницей идей насилия и приносить** народам Востока грубое вторжение и разрушение векового уклада. [Ю. М. Лотман. Русская культура послепетровской эпохи и христианская традиция (1991)]